# Calling different functions with AJAX from one controller LARAVEL

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I have a few functions in one controller, for example:

```
 public function cruise($id){...}
 public function block($id){...}
```

In web.php I added routes:

```
Route::post('/profile/{cruise}', 'UtilityController@cruise');
Route::post('/profile/{block}', 'UtilityController@block');
```

In my ajax in blade:

```
 function block() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{route('profile', $user->id)}}",   // PROBLEM HERE
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {formData: $data},
                success: function ($data) {
                    console.log('status = ' + status);
                },
                error: function (json) {
                    console.log(json);
                },
            })
        }
```

How can I define specific function route from my controller in ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the same route for 2 different controller methods

```
Route::post('/profile/{cruise}', 'UtilityController@cruise');
Route::post('/profile/{block}', 'UtilityController@block');
```

When you write  `Route::post('/profile/{cruise}',...` this part `{between_curly_braces}` is a wildcard.... in other words it's just the name of the variable that laravel will assign the value you are sending...

In your case it's `$user->id` and whatever you do it will always hit the first route in your routes file that corresponds that structure `post('/profile/{ }`

In order for this to work so you can hit different methods in your Controller you will have to separate the routes to hit different methods. Make these 2 Routes in routes file:

```
Route::post('/profile-cruise/{cruise}', 'UtilityController@cruise')->name('profile.cruise');
Route::post('/profile-block/{block}', 'UtilityController@block')->name('profile.block');
```

and in ajax functions hit the wanted routes something like:

```
function cruise() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{route('profile.cruise', $user->id)}}",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {formData: $data},
        success: function ($data) {
            console.log('status = ' + status);
        },
        error: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
        },
    })
}
```

and for cruise:

```
function block() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{route('profile.block', $user->id)}}",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {formData: $data},
        success: function ($data) {
            console.log('status = ' + status);
        },
        error: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
        },
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to cause your routes a colliding